# youtube_player_flutter Playback Speed in flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart, youtube-player-flutter

I am using youtube_player_flutter package for plating youtube videos in my flutter app. https://pub.dev/packages/youtube_player_flutter

I want to set custom playback Speed. In the documentation, changing playback rate is mentioned under features. But I cannot find the method for it. Any help will be appreciated.